# Shiny - Formatting data type based on dynamic Column Names using Rhandsontable

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity, rhandsontable

I am building a Shiny app that displays a Rhandsontable for users to insert values and submit table. However, the table displayed for user is dependent on a select input whose values are of different column names which could either be the same or might have a bit of difference. Most of the column with exist in all of the different templates which might be selected by users and I am sure about what data types they will be but for the fact that some new columns might exist and their data types were not set might make it difficult for the table to be previewed on the user interphase. The code below was design for one of the options from which users are suppose to select from to preview the table. I cannot seem to get my head around achieving my desired goal which is to make sure specific columns which will always be present will be given a data type and any other new column coming in will be given a data type. The column names of my table are dynamic and will keep changing based on user input from a select input on the user interphase as already mentioned.
Therefore, I wish to set the data type for each column every time the user selects a value from the select input which will show the table with its column names.

1. Is there a way I can do this using Rhandsontable?
2. Using this approach can I still maintain type of dropdown in some of my columns as shown in the code below?

```
DF
dataValues <- reactiveValues(data=DF)

output$TemperatureLimits <- renderRHandsontable({
  rhandsontable(dataValues$data,selectCallback = TRUE, readOnly = FALSE,rowHeaders = NULL, maxRows = total_rows()) %>%
    hot_col("Rep", type = "numeric") %>%
    hot_col("Date", dateFormat = "DDMMYYYY", type = "date", fillHandle=TRUE, direction="vertical") %>%
    hot_col("PlaID",type="text", fillHandle=TRUE, direction="vertical") %>%
    hot_col("StuID", type="text", fillHandle=TRUE, direction="vertical") %>%
    hot_col("Bac", type="dropdown", source=dropdownBac) %>%
    hot_col("Dru", type="dropdown", source=dropdownDru) %>%
    hot_col("Row",type="numeric") %>%
    hot_col("Col",type="numeric") %>%
    hot_col("ID", type="text", fillHandle=TRUE, direction="vertical", readOnly = TRUE) %>%
    hot_col("File",type="text", readOnly = TRUE) %>%
    hot_col("ExpeType",type="text", fillHandle=TRUE, direction="vertical",readOnly = TRUE) %>%
    hot_col("Conc",type="dropdown", source=dropdownConc) %>%
    hot_col("Day",type="text", fillHandle=TRUE, direction="vertical", readOnly = TRUE) %>%
    hot_col("FileRun",type="text", fillHandle=TRUE, direction="vertical",) %>%
    hot_table(stretchH = "all", highlightCol = TRUE)
```

Seeing that DF is reactive and does change, this means that when ever user selects another option from the select input the column names showed will be update and might be exactly the same or are prone to a few changes however some columns will still remain.